# Uncaught TypeError: A.LiferayItemSelectorDialog is not a constructor - Liferay Portal 7.4 GA 105

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui

I am using Liferay portal 7.4 GA 105, I am upgrading it from 7.2. So, I have faced issue that when to open a document and media dialogue box on a button click it shows an error on console that `A.LiferayItemSelectorDialog is not a constructor`. Although it works fine when using in Liferay 7.2.

Here is the JSP file having code/script to open a dialogue box.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" %>

 <%
 String itemSelectorURL = GetterUtil.getString(request.getAttribute("itemSelectorURL"));
 %>

 <aui:script use="liferay-item-selector-dialog">
    console.log("test");
    var parsedHtmlGeneratorId = '';
    jQuery_html('.chooseImage').on(
          'click', 
         function(event) {
         parsedHtmlGeneratorId = event.currentTarget.dataset.parsedid;
             var itemSelectorDialog = new A.LiferayItemSelectorDialog(  
                 {
                     eventName: 'ItemSelectedEventName',
                     on: {
                             selectedItemChange: function(event) {
                                 var selectedItem = event.newVal;

                                 if (selectedItem) {
                                     itemSrc = selectedItem.value
                                    var parsedItemId = '<portlet:namespace />' + parsedHtmlGeneratorId;
                                    document.getElementById(parsedItemId).value = itemSrc;
                                 }
                            }
                    },
                     title: 'Select Image',
                     url: '<%= itemSelectorURL.toString() %>'
                }
            );
            itemSelectorDialog.open();
        }
    );
     
</aui:script>
```

Here is my button which I used to call that script

```
<aui:button data="<%=dataMap%>" name="chooseImage"
                                    value="Browse" cssClass="chooseImage btn-primary  mt-1" />
```

I have added all the necessary code in the `portlet.java` file, including references to `itemSelector` and all the required code available in the Liferay documentation for its usage.

If anyone faces this problem, please recommend a solution and an approach to follow to resolve this issue in Liferay 7.4.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUI is on the way out, so there's a good probability that you'll have to migrate your code to a newer UI layer.

Luckily there's Liferay documentation about [how to implement an item selector](https://learn.liferay.com/w/dxp/building-applications/data-frameworks/implementing-an-item-selector) based on newer versions. It looks like it's now based on `Liferay.Util.openSelectionModal`, so your implementation will need to adapt to the new way.